# How to extract array index of data.frame using r

Tags: r

I have the data.frame below and I would like to extract the index array only. How to do that ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cnUJ.jpg)

Comment: data$col<-rownames(data) . then data$col this should work.

Comment: Thanks you very much. It's working. Harshal Gajare